# Capture output from attached docker container

Tags: docker

I am attempting to capture output from commands I run on an attached Docker container, but I can not figure out how to just get output from a command like `ls`.

The code below produces this:

```
[[<root@098c455d93ff:/# ls; ><echo 1987a><6ee-2aad-4713-831a-f8102bfde4b7 $?
><bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
>]]
```

Whereas I am trying to get only this:

```
[[<bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
>]]
```

The code:

```
'use strict'

Docker = require 'dockerode'
uuid = require 'node-uuid'
async = require 'async'
os = require 'os'
fs = require 'fs'

class Make

  d: new Docker
    host: '192.168.59.103'
    protocol: 'https'
    port: 2376
    ca: fs.readFileSync(process.env.DOCKER_CERT_PATH + '/ca.pem')
    cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.DOCKER_CERT_PATH + '/cert.pem')
    key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.DOCKER_CERT_PATH + '/key.pem')

  output: ''

  run: (cmd, callback) ->
    pid = uuid.v4()
    command = cmd + '; echo ' + pid + ' $?' + os.EOL
    @stream.on 'readable', =>
      data = @stream.read()
      # console.log data
      # look for exit code
      matchExit = data.match /(^[A-Za-z0-9-]{36})\s(\d+)$/m
      if matchExit isnt null and matchExit[1] is pid
        if matchExit[2] isnt '0'
          console.error 'Exit code: %d: %s', matchExit[2], command
        @stream.removeAllListeners 'readable'
        return callback()
      # look for command output
      matchOutput = data.match /([A-Za-z0-9-]{36})/
      if matchOutput is null
        @output += '<' + data + '>'
    @stream.write command

  setup: (callback) ->
    async.series [
      # create
      (callback) =>
        options =
          Image: 'ubuntu'
          Tty: true
          # AttachStdin: true
          # AttachStdout: true
          AttachStderr: true
          OpenStdin: true
          # StdinOnce: false
        @d.createContainer options, (err, @container) =>
          callback err
      # attach
      , (callback) =>
        options =
          stream: true
          stdin: true
          stdout: true
          stderr: true
        @container.attach options, (err, @stream) =>
          return callback err if err?
          @stream.setEncoding 'utf8'
          callback()
      # start
      , (callback) =>
        @container.start callback
    ], callback

  build: (callback) ->
    cmds = [
      'ls'
      # 'mkdir test'
      # 'cd test'
      # 'echo "hello world" > hello.txt'
      # 'cat hello.txt'
    ]
    runner = (cmd, callback) => @run cmd, callback
    async.eachSeries cmds, runner, callback


make = new Make()

make.setup (err) ->
  console.error err if err?
  make.build ->
    console.log '[[' + make.output + ']]'
    make.stream.end()
```

Comment: I'm confused by your implementation. The ‘docker logs‘ command is a simple way to get what you already got .  

You could just pipe the output of your command into a file mapped to the host environment with -v.   And why are you asking for a tty?

Comment: I'm doing this via Dockerode, a Node.js package, so while I guess it's easy using the commandline, I'm trying to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If it is loging functionality you want I wrote this gist with some examples.
https://gist.github.com/afolarin/a2ac14231d9079920864

The other thing you might consider if you are using v1.3 is the `docker exec` command which you can use to insert new processes into a running container.

Comment: container.exec looks good, and this might be the wrong place to ask, but I am also trying to capture if any of the commands error, thus ' $?'

Comment: Look at my gist. You can split the docker logs. `me@host~$ docker logs foo > stdout.log 2>stderr.log
....then....me@host~$ cat stdout.log
....then....me@host~$ cat stderr.log`